# Indexing in Azure table storage vs Google Appengine datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, azure-table-storage

Azure table storage and Google Appengine datastore are both no-sql key-value datastores. Google appengine indexes data on each of the columns so that you can do fast WHERE queries on each of the data column variable. E.g., lets say I am inserting data with following columns:
`Date Author Book Reviews`

Google appengine will go ahead and index data on each of these columns so that following queries are fast:

```
- get all rows WHERE Date == something
- get all rows WHERE Author == someone
- get all rows WHERE Book == title
- get all rows WHERE Reviews >= 4
```

but it looks like azure table storage does not index data on all the columns. It seems to index only the {partition key, row key} combination. Is that correct? This seems to be a significant shortcoming compared to google's datastore. Why this design? [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589791.aspx) is a workaround I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that PartionKey and RolWey values are the only two indexed properties. As you mentioned, you can work around this limitation.  Please see intra-partition secondary index pattern and inter-partition secondary index pattern in the following MSDN article for more details: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/.  The article also contains all you need to know about the Azure Table.

If you want to discuss more about the table design, you can drop us an email at ascl@microsoft.com.